# How can I go from Local to my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, local

I have a WordPress site made several months ago for testing.
There I wanted to "have fun" a bit and recreate it. The goal being to learn new tools, I decided to recreate it via the "Local" software to take it in hand and test it. I have now created this entire site locally.

I would like to know how I can use this local site and transfer it to replace my current site (which is therefore the old version).
Do you have the steps to do this? Could you explain to me?

Thank you to everyone who took the time to help me.
Good evening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand quite well what you want to do, but I supposed that you want to upload your website from local to online? If this what you wanna do I explain you:

1. You have to have a server with database and a domain hired. The domain has to point to the server IP.
2. Once you have it, you have to export the local database. You can do it with some plugin like Migrate DB, etc. to convert de url's to the new ones.
3. You have to import this database to the database from the server.
4. Once you have done this, you have to upload the programming files through FTP, SFTP to the server.
5. Important: you have to change wp-config.php file with the parameters from the new database.
6. Once the website is installed, I recommend you to go to the new admin site and save the permanentlinks.

And that's all.